# Will an isolated electron dissipate in space as energy?

Tags: electrons, conservation-laws, mass-energy

Will an isolated electron, if not further engaged in any interaction, dissipate in space as energy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, here is why.

An isolated electron possesses both spin and electric charge. Both of these are *conserved quantities*; whatever spin and charge values enter an equation for electron *decay*, those same values are *required* to show up in the decay products (whatever they might be).

In addition, the electron *itself* belongs to a family of particles called *leptons*, and if you have any leptons entering one side of a decay process or reaction, there *has* to be the exact same number of leptons leaving the other side of the process: *lepton number* is a *conserved quantity* too. Our universe is so structured that we cannot create spin, charge, or lepton number out of nothing, nor can we make any of them just disappear into nothing either.

This means that if you want to propose a mechanism for an electron to decay all by its lonely self into something else, that "something else" must exhibit lepton number = 1, charge number = -1, and spin number = 1/2.

Now, are there any other particles with the same values of those numbers that an electron can spontaneously decay into? Since a decay process that runs all by itself must turn some mass into energy, the decay product (some other particle) must be lighter than an electron. Since there are no leptons lighter than an electron that have spin 1/2 and charge -1, spontaneous decay of an isolated electron is *forbidden* by these conservation laws.

Comment: Lepton number is not conserved  when traversing an event horizon, right? On the other hand, outside the EH, you can never see it enter. I guess I'm trying to square lepton number conservation with the No-Hair Theorem.

Comment: Thanks, niels nielsen! So if I somehow manage to emit a single electron in vacuum, it will continue to be an electron and will still be "detectable". Do I get this right? Has this been made by someone?

Comment: @R.Romero, from our frame of reference outside the black hole, an electron falling into a black hole never crosses the event horizon and its charge resides just outside the event horizon.

Comment: @AdelinaMitkova, that is correct. You can cause a piece of metal to emit electrons by heating it up red-hot in a vacuum, and those electrons then zoom away into space as real electrons which you can then detect by a variety of means.

Comment: @AdelinaMitkova, you are right again. This principle is present in old-style *cathode ray tubes*, all types of " elektronniya lampa" (sorry for my unskilled language), both transmission and scanning electron microscopes, photoelectric tubes, and things like particle accelerators like the original SLAC electron accelerator in California.